# Render form through jQuery in Rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to create a dynamic, nested form using rails 5 and jQuery.  I can easily remove nested fields but am having a hard time adding them back.  My `_project_field.html.erb` is as follows:

```
<%= form_for @project do |project| %>      

  <%= project.label :description, class: 'col-md-2' %>
  <%= project.text_field :description, class: 'col-md-8' %>

  <%= project.label :lot, class: 'col-md-2' %>
  <%= project.text_field :lot, class: 'col-md-8' %>

  <%= project.fields_for :tests do |test| %>
    <%= render 'test_fields', :f => test %>
  <% end %>

  <%= link_to "Add Test", 'javascript:void(0);',  class: "add-link col-md-2" %>

  <%= project.hidden_field :user_id, value: current_user.id %>
  <%= project.submit "Submit", class: 'btn btn-primary col-md-2 col-md-offset-3' %>

<% end %>
```

and inside of that is the `_test_fields` form,

```
<div class="form-fields">
  <div class="row">

    <%= f.label :test_method_id, "Test Method", class: 'col-md-2' %>

    <div class="col-md-6 method-select">
      <%= f.select(:test_method_id, options_for_select(@methods, selected: f.object.test_method_id), include_blank: true) %>
    </div>

    <%= link_to "Remove", 'javascript:void(0);',  class: "remove-link col-md-2" %>

  </div>
</div>
```

when I click the "Add Test" link, it simply renders the string "<%= j render 'test_fields', :f => test %>". Here is that code:

```
//  assets/javascript/forms.js

$(".add-link").click(function() {
  console.log("add link");
  var html = '<%= j render \'test_fields\', :f => test %>'
  $(this).parent().append(html);
})
```

How can I go about adding field partials to nested forms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JavaScript code is doing it's job as it's supposed to. The reason this does not work is because you are trying to interpret ERB code in the browser.

`form.js` file is already loaded in the browser. But `'<%= j render \'test_fields\', :f => test %>'` is ERB code which is to be interpreted in the server.

So, for this to work as a dynamic form, you will need to:

1. Create an action in your `projects_controller` like `#add_form_field` 
   perhaps.
2. Define necessary route for the action in `routes.rb`. Which will most 
   probably give you a path like `project_add_form_field_path`
3. You will use this path in your link. i.e, instead of

   `<%= link_to "Add Test", 'javascript:void(0);',  class: "add-link col-md-2" %>`

   you will have something like:

   `<%= link_to "Add Test", project_add_form_field_path,  class: "add-link col-md-2", remote: true %>`
4. This is going to call the `#add_form_field` action in your 
   `projects_controller`. `remote: true` is going to make it asynchronous 
   so that your page won't reload of course.
5. So now the controller action is going to look for a related file in 
   the views folder. Since it'a an asynchronous call, it is going to 
   look for JavaScript file: `/views/project/add_form_field.js.erb`. You
   are going to want to put the JavaScript in your `form.js` file into
   this `add_form_file.js.erb` file. Now the `'<%= j render 
   \'test_fields\', :f => test %>'` bit is going to be processed in the 
   server and things should work as you desire.

   Also in the JavaScript, I'd prefer `"<%= j render 
   'test_fields', :f => test %>"` over usage of escape characters.

Comment: This flow seems to work for my use in Rails 5, thanks!